# EasyMonkeyDevice touch sometimes tap on wrong coordinates

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

My program is trying to establish a VPN connection, thus, I get the Android message about "Connection Request - your software wants to setup a VPN connection ... Only accept if you trust the source".
From uiautomationviewer I saw the ID is id/button1. So, I've used this

```
easy_device.touch(By.id('id/button1'), MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

The OK button according to uiautomationviewer is at `[810,1162][978,1288]`, But monkeyrunner taps on `X=866, Y=709`

```
170725 15:43:I [main] [com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager] Monkey Command: tap 866 709.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC monkeyrunner messes dialog coords. Give [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) a try and it should do it right.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoTorresMilano, I tried but from some reason AndroivViewClient is not working ok on my mac. I've managed by calculating the position relative to other views.

Comment: If you create another question detailing your problem and tag it *androidviewclient* I will try to solve it.